# Pycharm: Expected type 'Integral', got 'str' instead

Tags: python, pycharm

I just installed PyCharm 3.4 and get some new warnings. Not just here but in many places. Code is fine of course. Can someone translate what PyCharm trying to tell me and how to silence this messages?

[image: screenshot]
[more...](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV7Ek.png)

Comment: Presumably PyCharm thinks `item` is a list or tuple.

Comment: Please post more of your code, specifically, the part where `items` is assigned.

Comment: There is a bigger screenshot. Link "more..." on the right side.

Comment: A screenshot is a very difficult way to view code, can you just add the code as text?

Comment: Probably you'd have to ask some pycharm developers --- pycharm inspections have a lot of false-positives.

Comment: @avalanchy you might want to address an answer.  BUT.  I would maybe go about using a generator here, since you end up filtering which will need to walk the entire set anyways.  That way it wont create an array and assign info until it is walked with your filter.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Based on the 'more...' screenshot, it looks like Pycharm might be interpreting the map() as though the two terms around the comma are both part of the lambda, i.e. the lambda just returns a 2-tuple instead of treating it as two parameters to the map() function.

Things to try:

- Add parentheses inside the map()
- look for redefinitions of the map() builtin itself that might be confusing Pycharm

*EDIT*

You inspired me to go learn more about Python and Pycharm. :)

It looks like Pycharm is happier with using a list comprehension than with `map()`.  Using this sample data:

```
data = {
    'data': {
        'children': [
            {'data': {'url': 'http://1.com/', }, },
            {'data': {'url': 'http://2.com/', }, },
        ]
    },
}
```

if you write the code like you did, then you get the error:

```
items = map(lambda children: children['data'], data['data']['children'])
for item in items:
    print item['url']  # Pycharm shows warning on 'url'
```

But if you use a list comprehension instead, then Pycharm is happy:

```
items = [x['data'] for x in data['data']['children']]
for item in items:
    print item['url']  # No warning from Pycharm
```

And the output is the same for both.

ISTR reading that list comprehensions are preferred over `map()` nowadays anyway, so maybe Pycharm is nudging us in that direction?

Comment: why are list comprehensions preferred over `map()`?

Comment: Joinning the question

Answer (score 5):

You can also get rid of this notification if you get the value from the dictionary with `get()`. This should work: 
`fresh_urls = {item.get('url') for item in items}`